# ProcessBuilder - hanging on the readLine() method

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

Running the following simple program:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-Command", "dir");
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    System.out.println("Exit");
```

Never reaches the "Exit" println - just hangs infinitely on the `readLine()` method. I understand this is (most probably) caused by the fact that powershell does not output `\n` in the last line and `readLine` is not sure whether the end has been reached or not. Is there a way to get over this issue and read the input stream correctly? BTW. `inheritIO` method on processbuilder resulted in the same issue...

UPDATE

This:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-Command", "dir");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
//        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
//        String line;
//        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
//            System.out.println(line);
//        }
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Exit");
```

Also hangs infinitely...

Answer (score 1):

Powershell isn't ending. I would probably use Java to list a directory, but this should work with your example.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("dir");
```

Comment: So I need to provide sth like `exit` at the end?

Comment: I suppose you could close stdout instead (from PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the processbuilder hanging on readline()

Specifically, windows 10, running a cmd.exe command that starts a bash and runs a script.

The problem was fixed by closing the input of the process:

```
     Process process = pb.start();
     process.getOutputStream().flush();
     process.getOutputStream().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. I tried making a new project with your code (added in a few try-catch and print statements), and it works for me. Here is what I used;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-Command", "dir");
        Process p;
        try {
            p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start powershell");
            return;
        }
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        System.out.println("Begin!");
        try {
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("reading...");
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read line");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Exit");

    }

}
```

And here is the resulting console output,

```
Begin! reading...

reading...

reading...
    Directory: C:\Users\AbrahamV\workspace\201_stackoverflow reading...

reading...

reading... Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name           reading...
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                       reading... d----        12/10/2013   9:29 PM            bin            reading... d----        12/10/2013   9:27 PM            src            reading...
-a---        12/10/2013   9:27 PM        232 .classpath                                                                 reading...
-a---        12/10/2013   9:27 PM        393 .project                                                                   reading...

reading...

Exit
```

The output wasn't instantaneous. Took a few moments before anything was printed out.